# Is lazy instantiation just another name for proxy pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

What is the difference in these? I cannot find such "lazy instantiation" as a pattern [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) and [there](http://www.oodesign.com/), but somehow I feel lazy instantiation is just an another term for the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, although you could use lazy instantiation inside a proxy, they are not really related concepts.

**Lazy instantiation**

```
getBar() {
  if (bar == null)
    bar = new Foo();
  return bar;
}
```

**Proxy**

```
getBar() {
   return realObject.getBar();
}
```

**Proxy with lazy instantiation**

```
getBar() {
  if (realObject == null)
    realObject = new Foo();
   return realObject.getBar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, superb!. It seems proxy acts like API for working with hidden (and maybe) external objects (for example 3rd party library objects). It's convenient if you don't want to tie your code to 3rd party lib, especially if it will change latter (IMHO then it might evolve into adapter pattern).

Comment: Right, the `Proxy` is useful for wrapping external data sources and 3rd party interfaces behind an object.  Often I use it for hiding/swapping implementations or testability.  It is most similar to the `Facade` and `Adapter` patterns so you may want to look into those as well.

Comment: And what would be the essential difference between proxy and facade patterns? Both ways you have a wrapper class...

Comment: Basically the same thing, but `Facade` implies your intention is hiding messy interactions often between multiple objects (typically 3rd party libraries).  `Proxy` implies you are wrapping a service possibly because there are multiple implementations you want to use.  It is a subtle difference, mostly based on intent.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same thing.  In a nutshell:

Lazy initialization is when you wait until you need something before you create it.

The proxy pattern is when you control access to an underlying object.  The proxy pattern might use lazy initialization to create the thing it proxies, but you don't have to.

For example, in my javascript code I have something like

```
if (!this._pane ) this._pane = ... // create pane lazily
// now use pane
```

which creates a pane that I am going to show only when I need it.  This has the advantage of avoiding the cost of creating the pane until the user reaches it (which they might not even get to.)  That's lazy initialization.

The proxy pattern might use lazy initialization, but it is not another term for it.

Comment: Could you give an examples when do you use proxy pattern?

Answer (score 1):

No, lazy initialization is not another term for proxy. You *could* use proxies to implement lazy initialization, but not all proxies are lazy initialization.

Answer (score 0):

No, with a proxy you are working with an intermediate thing and really have no idea what it's doing behind the scenes.  With lazy init, you are working with the actual object (it just isn't created until first needed).